# Certifcate Warning For SSL Site In Facebook In App Browser

Tags: android, facebook, ssl, nginx

OK, I have a bit of a strange issue. I have an ssl-only website secured with a Comodo PositiveSSL certificate and the certificate is installed properly on an NGINX server and has been working with no issue.

Every major browser renders the site and links to it on Desktop / Mobile with no certificate errors, however on the Android version of the Facebook mobile app, no matter what, the in-app browser displays a security certificate warning. The regular Android browser / Chrome work just fine in addition to the in-app browser on the Facebook iOS app having no problems whatsoever.

I have tried nearly everything including re chaining the certificate, enabling only secure cypher suites, making sure there is no plain HTTP content and using an NGINX server block to redirect plain HTTP requests to the HTTPS site. My users on this combo are understandably beginning to get a bit frustrated.

Comment: Did you have a look at the analysis for your site by [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)? If this does not help post the URL of the site.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I have ran the URL of the site through SSL labs and it has consistently gotten an "A" rating with no issues reported.

Comment: Could you provide the details of the certificate warning, i.e. what does it complain about (name, issuer...)? And have you also checked that there are no chain issues shown by SSLLabs (you still can get an A rating even with chain issues). Finally, could you provide the URL?